# Regex check url and letter

Tags: regex

I try to build two regex .net who :

1)check if url start by "http:// or https://" and contains minimum 4 letters tolower AND contains minimum 4letters toupper.

ex:http://www.abcdeABCDE.com match

http://www.abcde.com not match

http://www.Abcde.com not match

I try this regex but nor work:

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.]+(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,}(?=.*[a-z]).{4,}$
```

2)check if url start by "http:// or https://" and contains minimum 30 letters(  contains tolower,toupper and digit) without separation

ex : http://www.qsdfmjk12mqsKL54JMDSFFMLKJSFD126.com match
http://www.qsdfmjk12mqsKL54.com not match

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should do the job:

```
^(?:https?://)(?=(?:.*[A-Z]){4,})(?=(?:.*[a-z]){4,})
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : start of string
  (?:           : start non capture group
    https?://   : that contains http:// ot https://
  )             : end group
  (?=           : lookahead
    (?:         : non capture group
      .*[A-Z]   : one or more any char followed by uppercase letter
    ){4,}       : group must be present 4 or more times
  )             : end of lookahead
  (?=           : lookahead
    (?:         : non capture group
      .*[a-z]   : one or more any char followed by uppercase letter
    ){4,}       : group must be present 4 or more times
  )             : end of lookahead
```

For the second regex, use:

```
^(?:https?://)[a-zA-Z0-9]{30,}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : start of string
  (?:           : start non capture group
    https?://   : that contains http:// ot https://
  )             : end group
  [a-zA-Z0-9]{30,}  : at least 30 characters lower or upper case or digit
```

For both regex, if http is optional, use `^(?:https?://)?`

Comment: yes thank you, I have one last question, if I would like the regex stop until the next slash, how to do? ex: [http://www.test.com/qsdfqdqsfsdqfsdqfqsfqsdfqsfqsFDSQsfd131/](http://www.test.com/qsdfqdqsfsdqfsdqfqsfqsdfqsfqsFDSQsfd131/) not match ; [http://www.test.com](http://www.test.com) without slash not match also

Comment: @Zoners: Add `.+[^/]$` at the end of regex.

Answer (score 0):

The second example could be something like this
`^(?:https?:\/\/)[a-z0-9.]{30,}\.[a-z]{2,}$`

see https://regex101.com/r/dMuv7q/1

Comment: I edit my response, not work,  "[https://www.Abcde.com](https://www.Abcde.com)" -->contains only one letters toupper and not 4 letters

Answer (score 0):

```
^https?://(?=.*[A-Z]{4,})(?=.*[a-z]{4,}).*  
^https?://[a-zA-Z0-9\\.]{30,}
```

Comment: I try first regex [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ehttp%28s%29%3f%3a%2f%2f.*%5ba-z%5d%7b4%2c%7d%5bA-Z%5d%7b4%2c%7d.*&i=http%3a%2f%2fwww.CCCCABCDECclubisdfqfgc.com) it's not work on my example and I have more 4letters to uppercase AND more 4letters in lowercase

Comment: I Try a new test [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5ehttp%28s%29%3f%3a%2f%2f%28www%5c.%29%3f%28%28%5ba-z%5d%7b4%2c%7d%5bA-Z%5d%7b4%2c%7d%29%7c%28%5bA-Z%5d%7b4%2c%7d%5ba-z%5d%7b4%2c%7d%29%29.*&i=http%3a%2f%2fwww.FsdfFFFFFcittyTESTTOTafsdqf.com) the string "FsdfFFFFFcittyTESTTOTafsdqf" contains more 4 character toupper and tolower

Comment: the second regex matches: `http://...................................................................................`